# How to add linenumbers to figure captions?

Tags: tables, captions, line-numbering

I'd like to add linenumbers to my TeX-file. I found the packe `lineno` which I'm using as follows:

```
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
```

Unfortunately line numbers are not added to the figure captions and table captions. Is there an easy way to also include captions to the line numbering?

Comment: They are floats, what is the point in adding line numbers, when they have captions?

Comment: @HarishKumar: I don't understand your comment. My figure cations are quite long (20 lines). I simply want those lines to have numbers like lines in the main text.

Comment: would it be acceptable for a line-numbered caption to have line numbers (re-)starting at 1?  (i can't give an answer, but maybe this would help someone else.  the answer by @HarishKumar implies that it's not possible for text lines in a float to have numbers in sequence with line numbers in the main text, since the position of a float is uncertain.)

Comment: The `lineno` package has an extension just for this purpose. Immediately before your `\caption` call, type `\internallinenumbers`. It won't work well if your caption lines have different spacing from `\baselineskip`, but it will work in a pinch.